# Two dimensional array Scan Crash

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

scan arr function problems.

```
void scan_arr(double ar[3][5]) // Declares that it is a 3 x 5
{

    int x;
    int y;
    printf("Enter arrays of 3x5\n");

    for( x = 0; x < 3; x++ ) // Shows that this loop shall be done 3 times 
    {
        for( y = 0; y < 5; y++ ) // Shows that 5 times * the number of the first loop
        {
            scanf("%lf",ar[x][y]); // Scans @ x * y and terminates after first input
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are missing an ampersand in front of `ar[x][y]`:

```
scanf("%lf", &ar[x][y]);
//           ^
//           |
//          Here
```

`scanf` expects an address of the item where the value is to be stored, so you need to use the "take address" operator `&`.

Comment: Riiiight!! I feel so stupid :). Well i guess everyone can make such a simple mistake in the learning of programming.

Comment: @user2354897 Absolutely, this is a very common mistake. Even experienced programmers make it from time to time, because the compiler cannot detect it. If the fix works for you, consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would let others know that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a badge on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass address of the array's element of the `scanf` function, so replace this:

```
scanf("%lf",ar[x][y]);
```

with

```
scanf("%lf", &ar[x][y]);
```